# Multiple Errors on test code with Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I am following this tutorial, for testing and this was a little test/lesson we were doing. I keep getting errors on the 11th line. Can someone tell me whats going on? This is the code, except its not complete.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Test2Coding {

    public static void main(String[] args) {} 

    {}

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int age;
    System.out.println("How old are you?"); 
}
```

Comment: The problem was mainly in formatting, write your code in a readable way, most errors will just appear right after :D

Answer (score 1):

You have some extra brackets in the code. Your 3 lines of code should be directly inside the brackets after the main method declaration.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the brackets you are not using

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Test2Coding {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int age;
    System.out.println("How old are you?");
}
```

Comment: Okay, problem, I still get the error on my print line saying Syntax Error on token "How old are you?", delete this token.  The other one is Syntax Error on tokens, misplaced constructs.